# Principal Component Analysis - Two approaches, yielding different results

Tags: python, python-3.x, pca

I'm trying to conduct Principal Component Analysis manually.

However, I've witnessed an issue:

**Problem: when conducting PCA "manually" from scratch, using two different approaches, I don't get the same results**

Let me showcase the issue by means of an example:

Consider the following numpy array **(1)**:

```
x = np.array([
    [1.5, 2.3, 5.2, 3.2, 5.5],
    [3.5, 4.2, 6.5, 8.9, 7.5],
    [9.6, 8.2, 7.1, 9.3, 1.1],
    [3.1, 2.7, 2.9, 3.5, 9.6],
    [1.1, 6.7, 2.3, 3.5, 9.5]])
```

In the first approach, I first calculate the Covariance Matrix **(2)**:

```
CovM = np.cov(x.T)
```

From the covariance matrix, I calculate the eigenvector and eigenvalues **(3)**:

```
eig_vals, eig_vecs = np.linalg.eig(CovM)
```

I then sort my eigen values from highest to lowest (needed for PC calculation) **(4)**:

```
eig_pairs = [(np.abs(eig_vals[i]), eig_vecs[:,i]) for i in range(len(eig_vals))]
eig_pairs.sort(key=lambda x: x[0], reverse=True)
```

I then store my eigenvectors **(5)**:

```
matrix_w = np.hstack((eig_pairs[0][1].reshape(5,1), 
                  eig_pairs[1][1].reshape(5,1),
                  eig_pairs[2][1].reshape(5,1),
                  eig_pairs[3][1].reshape(5,1)
                ))
```

Calculating my principal components I get **(6)**:

```
x.dot(matrix_w)

array([[ 1.57663265, -2.09793105,  6.2812378 ,  0.02538662],
   [ 5.18837375, -4.40212324, 11.50839994,  0.36124448],
   [13.58239293, -5.93222094,  6.90492473,  1.19626484],
   [-0.23287223, -5.19146231,  8.05750048,  3.01045736],
   [-0.33881008, -8.33915097,  7.44838336, -0.16441424]])
```

**Now, note these results, they're going to be different from the second approach and that's exactly the issue! While they have the same magnitude they differ in signs (positive and negative values)**

Now, for the second approach:

Consider the same numpy array from before (1). I will reuse that part, but calculate everything else from scratch, hence:

Covariance matrix for numpy array, x, can be found as: **(7)**:

```
cov_mat = np.cov(x.T)
```

Similarily, we can calculate the eigenvalues and eigenvectors as before **(8)**:

```
eigen_values, eigen_vectors = np.linalg.eigh(cov_mat)
```

Now, I can sort my eigenvalues from highest to lowest, using **(9)**:

```
sorted_index = np.argsort(eigen_values)[::-1]
sorted_eigenvalue = eigen_values[sorted_index]
sorted_eigenvectors = eigen_vectors[:,sorted_index]
```

I choose to retain 4 components (first 4 PC), hence **(10)**:

```
n_components = 4
eigenvector_subset = sorted_eigenvectors[:,0:n_components]
```

Similarly, as before, I can calculate the principal components **(11)**:

```
np.dot(eigenvector_subset.transpose(),x.transpose()).transpose()

array([[ -1.57663265,   2.09793105,   6.2812378 ,   0.02538662],
   [ -5.18837375,   4.40212324,  11.50839994,   0.36124448],
   [-13.58239293,   5.93222094,   6.90492473,   1.19626484],
   [  0.23287223,   5.19146231,   8.05750048,   3.01045736],
   [  0.33881008,   8.33915097,   7.44838336,  -0.16441424]])
```

The above, shows the very issue. When comparing the results of **(11)** with **(6)**, I see that I get different signs (positive and negative) for some reason that I can't explain - I tried to resolve the issue, one thing I noticed is if I use the definition of **(3)** i.e., eig_vals and eig_vecs instead of **(8)** when sorting in **(9)** I do indeed get the same results, but this seems a bit suspicious, given that the way I calculate the covariance matrices and the eigenvalues and eigenvectors are essentially the same in either approach, or am I missing something?

Please let me know if my question is not clear and consise

Comment: To follow up, I made an interesting finding.

It appears that the following pieces of codes, causes the issue: 

"np.linalg.eig(CovM)" and "np.linalg.eigh(cov_mat)"

In particular "eig and eigh", for some reason they don't yield the same results.

Comment: As you write, you used two different methods for calculating the eigenvectors; these are ambiguous w.r.t. a factor `-1`; hence, one of them returned eigenvectors some of which point in the opposite direction (check `matrix_w` vs. `eigenvector_subset`).

Comment: That sounds plausible, however, it appears the issue relates to how the eigenvector and eigenvalues were calculated, in particular, the use of "eig" or "eigh" in the following code snippet "np.linalg.eigh(cov_mat)", when aligning these two, such that we're using "eigh"  or "eig" for either case, it resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:** I found the issue, it relates to "eig" and "eigh" when calculating the eigenvector and eigenvalues. I was using either formulation in the two approaches, hence the different results.

Comment: Now the question is why two methods have different results? They are supposed to calculate eigenvalues and eigenvectors. And which one is true?

Comment: I found this answer: 



eigh guarantees you that the eigenvalues are sorted and uses a faster algorithm that takes advantage of the fact that the matrix is symmetric. If you know that your matrix is symmetric, use this function.
Attention, eigh doesn't check if your matrix is indeed symmetric, it by default just takes the lower triangular part of the matrix and assumes that the upper triangular part is defined by the symmetry of the matrix.

Comment: Could you include your last comment in your answer to clarify it?

Comment: @Shayan Eigenvectors are determined only up to a factor of `-1`; i.e. if `v` is an eigenvector then `-v` is an equivalent "candidate". There is not true/false or right/wrong, it's up to the algorithm whether it considers `v` or `-v` as the eigenvector. `eigh` is a specialized algorithm which makes use of the symmetry of the matrix, hence it can take a different computation path than `eig`.